# Call old F77 routines from F90 main program

Tags: fortran, fortran90, fortran77

I have to use some old 77 routines in my F90 code.

In the main program, is it mandatory to declare the 77 subroutines as "external"?

cause otherwise it says "This name does not have a type, and must have an explicit type".

Comment: In principle - no. In your case - maybe? Could you show us some code/compile options? Are the FORTRAN 77 routines in independent files or in libraries?

Comment: @AlexanderVogt in fact it is written in an independent file, maybe you heard about this routine, "DBCPOL.f" developed by ISML used to minimize a constrained function...

Answer (score 1):

Your error message seem to imply that the subroutine you are calling has been used as a function.  The problem would be in your calling statement.   Likely you have accidentally used a subroutine as a function, or made a typo in the program.